# jodconverter can't find officeHome, Using docsplit in centOS 5

Tags: java, ruby, openoffice.org, jodconverter

I'm trying to set up a server that will do document conversions using [docsplit](http://documentcloud.github.com/docsplit/).  The machine I'm setting it up on is running centOS 5.  When I try to do a basic conversion from the command line I get this error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: officeHome doesn't exist  or is not a directory:
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration.buildOfficeManager(DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration.java:165)
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.cli.Convert.main(Convert.java:111)
```

I've tried setting office.home system property in java but that doesn't work.  Since I'm using docsplit is there any way I can manual tell jodconverter what the office home directory is?

Answer (score 0):

make a symbolic link

```
[root@sakura opt]# pwd
/opt
[root@sakura opt]# ln -s /opt/libreoffice3.4 libreoffice
```